# Python: Return two square brackets, what does this mean? Can someone explain how this code works?

Tags: python, return, brackets

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a07f8.png)

Can someone explain how this code works? What kind of 'theme' is this in python? If month = 1, the code returns 31.

```
def days_in_month(month): 
    return [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month-1]
```

Comment: `[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]` is a list literal. `[month-1]` is accessing the `month-1`th index of that list.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list with `[]`. You are indexing it with [month-1]. When you pass month = 1, you are indexing 1 - 1 = 0, which is the element at the 0th index, also the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
def days_in_month (month) :
    return [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month-1]
```

The above code simply returns an index from the `[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]` list. This is similar like storing a list like

```
lst =  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

and accessing the values like `lst[month-1]`.

In your case, you are passing parameter as 1, hence it is indexing 0 ( `month - 1` ) of the list and so it returns `[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [0]` which is 31. It can be considered similar to `lst[0]` if you are storing the list in a variable and then indexing it.